# Reading a gz file and keeping track of position in file

Tags: java, io

So, here is the situation:

I have to read big .gz archives (GBs) and kind of "index" them to later on be able to retrieve specific pieces using random access.
In other words, I wish to read the archive line by line, and be able to get the specific location in the file for any such line. (so that I can jump directly to these specific locations upon request). (PS: ...and it's UTF-8 so we cannot assume 1 byte == 1 char.)

So, basically, what I just need is a BufferedReader which keeps track of its location in the file. However, this doesn't seem to exist.

Is there anything available or do I have to roll my own?

*A few additional comments:*

- I cannot use BufferedReader directly since the file location corresponds to what has been buffered so far. In other words, a multiple of the internal buffer size instead of the line location.
- I cannot use InputStreamReader directly for performance reasons. Unbuffered would be way to slow, and, btw, lacks convenience methods to read lines.
- I cannot use RandomAccessFile since 1. it's zipped, and 2. RandomAccessFile uses "modified" UTF-8

I guess the best would be use a kind of of buffered reader keeping track of file location and buffer offset ...but this sounds quite cumbersome. But maybe I missed something. Perhaps there is already something existing to do that, to read files line by lines and keep track of location (even if zipped).

Thanks for tips,

Arnaud

Answer (score 4):

I think [jzran](http://code.google.com/p/jzran/) could be pretty much what you're looking for:

> It's a Java library based on the
>   zran.c sample from zlib.
>
> You can preprocess a large gzip
>   archive, producing an "index" that can
>   be used for random read access.
>
> You can balance between index size and
>   access speed.

Comment: ...well, as you stated it, it is actually a wrapper over the zran lib via access to the jna (native access library) ...so it first add several dependencies: jzran, jna, zran and is not really cross platform anymore. It also misses the ability to read line by line like a classical reader, but just read bytes so you still have to make the conversion to UTF-8 chars. ...I have the feeling it is really not an optimal solution

Comment: If you want an "all-in-one-solution" you will have to write it on your own. Files - especially compressed one - are always processed in form of an InputStream in Java. If you want it in character form use an InputStreamReader.

Comment: I agree with Robert. Nonetheless, jzran or an own more cross-platform port of zran.c would be good starting points and you can add things like the UTF-8 parsing.

Comment: Well... somehow this is crazy. Java has all ingredients ready (classes for random access, to decompress gzip data, to buffer, to convert to UTF-8) ...they just don't combine AT ALL together!!! That io and nio don't share any common interface is just totally crazy. You want to use GZipInputStream with RandomAccessFile? Well, bad luck, you can't. ...just completely insane.

Comment: @arnaud: Well, gzip isn't designed for random access, things like zran.c were developed later to get something similar to random access, so you can't really blame Java for not having a built-in gZip random access class - just combining gZip decompression and random access simply won't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `mark()`, `markSupported()` and `skip()`.

This methods are declared both in InputStream and Reader, so you are welcome to use them.

Comment: mark is used if you want to reset the stream back to this position afterwards. It doesn't provide you the information about the location itself.

Answer (score 0):

GZIP compression does not support seeking. Previous data blocks are needed to build compression tables...